# res.send() displays [object object], can't access properties

Tags: javascript, json, rest, express

im just in the first days of learning REST API's with express. Why does this code console.logs user correctly `{ name: 'Test', id: 1 }`, but when im sending response, i got `[Object object]` displayed on the screen. I also cannot access user properties, but if I `JSON.stringify(user))`, it has all the properties set.

Im using `app.use(express.json())` right after the requires.

```
const users = []
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = { 
        name: req.body.firstName,  // firstName to nazwa inputu z html
        id: users.length + 1
    }

    const valid = true;
    if (valid) {
        users.push(newUser)
        res.redirect(`/users/${newUser.id}`)
    }
})

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
        const user = users.find(elem => elem.id == req.params.id)
        console.log(user)
        res.send(`GET user wit id ${req.params.id} ${user}`)
    })
```

Comment: `const valid = true; if (valid) { }`, why do you check the value of a constant?

Comment: You're responding with a string. And the result of (implicitly) calling `.toString()` on an object is the string `[Object object]`

Comment: @Suboptimierer its just not done yet, simply for learning purposes

Comment: @Andreas how to parse info from user then? and access its properties within res.send()? I want for example to display ${user.name}

Comment: How about `res.send(user)` and have the client create an English string?

Answer (score 0):

As [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) pointed, you are converting an Object to String.

If you want to see a representation of an object as a String, you can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Do it this way instead:

```js
const myObject = { a: 3 }
const myVariable = 4

console.log(`${myVariable} ${JSON.stringify(myObject)}`) // 4 {"a":3}
```

Applied to your code:

```js
res.send(`GET user wit id ${req.params.id} ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
```